# авторизация интранет проекта

Tags: asp.net

Добрый день
Я новичок в веб програмированиии и нужна помощь в авторизация интранет проекта.
Мне нужно содать 2 метода авторизации. В зависимости от пользователя система будет выдавать заранее прописанное меню.
Все пользователи в Домене. Сервер находится в Домене.
По умолчанию авторизация должна быть по текущему пользователю без никакой форм для авторизации. Но если другой человек, например начальник хочет получить свое меню он должен открыть форму для логина. 
Я не хочу накладывать ограничения в зависимости от страниц или папок. С момента смены пользователя и получения соотвествующего меню система будет проверять по текущему пользователю каждую запущенную страницу на право доступа через функцию проверки прав в AD.
Буду рад помощи. 
Michael

Comment: Hello, I see you're not Russian, but there's a good site to learn this. It's on Russian, but you can translate this: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/